# Load Failed image into HTML

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 1;
    window.onunload = function() {
      debugger;
    }

    function Para() {
      i = i + 1;
      var Source = document.getElementById('P').src;
      document.getElementById('P').src = Source.replace(i - 1, i);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div><img alt="image" id="P" src="Images/Para/P-1.jpg"></div>
  <div><img id="Q" src="Images/Q/P-1-Q-1.jpg" </div>
    <div><img id="A" src="Images/A/P-1-Q-1-A-1.png"></div> <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Next Parigraph" onclick="Para()" /> <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Next Question" /> <input id="Button3" type="button" value="Next Answer" /> </body>

</html>
```

actually I want a create html page which can load images. But this code returns load failed p-3.jpg. i could not understand why this is happening.First it loads P-1.jpg after p-2.jpg and after clicking Second time it not load and gives load Failed.Please Help

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly then i think the problem is here with you `replace()` function , js `replace()` function replace the first parameter with its second parameter . so when you are taking the src of img object by

```
var Source = document.getElementById('P').src;
```

it is taking the whole src of the object , according to this here you have image path also correct ? 
which is `Images/Para/P-1.jpg` , so when you are replacing the src by using replace function , in the next it retain only the value of `i = i + 1;` , 
i think you can try something like this

```
Source.replace("Images/Para/P-"+i - 1+".jpg", "Images/Para/P-"+i+".jpg");
```

to suggest you about something i can say please follow the convection of variable declaration , here you used `var Source` there is reserved keyword `Source` in JavaScript. it may conflict with the reserved keyword , 
please let me know you get it done correctly . if not then feel free to ask me again

Answer (score 0):

This works by me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 1;
    window.onunload = function() {
      debugger;
    }

    function Para() {
      var previous = i;
      var previousP = "P-" + previous.toString();
      i = i + 1;
      var Source = document.getElementById('P').src;

      var newP = "P-" + i.toString();
      var res = Source.replace(previousP, newP);
      document.getElementById('P').src = res;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div><img alt="image" id="P" src="/Images/Para/P-1.jpg"></div>
  <div><img id="Q" src="/Images/Q/P-1-Q-1.jpg" </div>
    <div><img id="A" src="/Images/A/P-1-Q-1-A-1.png"></div> <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Next Parigraph" onclick="Para()" /> <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Next Question" /> <input id="Button3" type="button" value="Next Answer" /> </body>

</html>
```